# React + Jest/Testing Library: Testing a conditionally rendered element not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, pokeapi

I'm trying to test a component with @testing-library/react and @testing-library/user-event. My component has a input field and when the length of the string is equal or more than 2, I suggest some possible results by filtering an array with the input text, and then I show a list of a maximum of 3 of these suggestions.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (search.length >= 2) suggestSearch();
    else setSuggestItems([]);
}, [search]);

function suggestSearch() {
    const suggest = battleItems.filter(
        function (this: any, item) {
            if (this.count < 3 && item.name.indexOf(search) >= 0) {
                this.count++;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        },
        { count: 0 }
    );

    setSuggestItems(suggest);
}
```

```
<form
    data-testid="item-form"
    onSubmit={(e) => handleItemSubmit(e)}
>
  <input
      name="item"
      defaultValue=""
      placeholder="Item name"
      autoComplete="off"
      onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
      data-testid="item-input"
    />
</form>

{suggestItems && suggestItems.length > 0 && (
    <ul>
        {suggestItems.map((item: BattleItem) => (
            <li
                key={item.name}
                onClick={() => searchItem(item.name)}
            >
                {formatName(item.name)}
            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
)}
```

I'm trying to test that behavior, and what I have now is the following test (It's a Pokémon related app):

```
it("should suggest items when the user types in the field", async () => {
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AddItem setItem={mockSetItem} />
        </Provider>
    );

    const input = screen.getByTestId("item-input");

    await userEvent.type(input, "choice");

    const firstSuggestion = await screen.findByText("Choice Band");
    const secondSuggestion = await screen.findByText("Choice Scarf");
    const thirdSuggestion = await screen.findByText("Choice Specs");

    expect(firstSuggestion).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(secondSuggestion).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(thirdSuggestion).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

But the test fails by not finding an element that matches the text (the component works in the browser). How can I test this / What am I doing wrong?

The output of the test (It doesn't show the suggestion list):

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <form data-testid="item-form">
              <input
                autocomplete="off"
                data-testid="item-input"
                name="item"
                placeholder="Item name"
                value=""
               />
            </form>
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
```